# Plotly subplots. Just only one sublot must have same scale ratio

Tags: python, plotly

There are 4 graphs in subplots, but only one should have the same scale on the x, y axes
Subplots:

```
fig = make_subplots(
            rows=3, cols=2, 
            shared_xaxes=True,
            specs=[[{'rowspan':3},{}],
                    [None,{}],
                    [None,{}],
                    ]
                    )
fig.append_trace(
                 {'x':time,
                  'y':x,
                  'mode':'lines+markers',
                  'type':'scatter'
                  }, 1,2
                  )
fig.append_trace(
                 {'x':time,
                  'y': y,
                  'mode':'lines+markers',
                  'type':'scatter'
                  },2,2
                  )
fig.append_trace(
                 {'x':time,
                  'y': t,
                  'mode':'lines+markers',
                  'type':'scatter'
                  },3,2
                  )
fig.append_trace(
                 {'x':x,
                  'y':y,
                  'mode':'markers',
                  'type':'scatter',
                    }, 1,1          # Only in this subplot I need same scale ratio  
                )
fig.update_layout(height=700,
template="plotly_white",
margin=dict(
    t=10,
    b=0
    ))
```

I need only one subplot with position (1,1) has the same scale ratio. How can I do this? Thanks!!!

Comment: If we had data on toys, many respondents would be able to do this more quickly.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dMch5hgKBvP6eTWLIquoMtlceBxEJdph/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to insert data here correctly

Comment: I tried to run the code with the sample data you posted. To confirm your question, is your goal to match the height of the (1,1) graph with the height of the three right pieces?

Comment: No. The 3 pieces on the right have a common x-axis scale (time) and that's enough. I need both axes of the left graph (1,1)  to have the same scale. Only the left graph needs to be changed

Comment: The graph on the left has 9 ticks on the y-axis, but only 2 ticks on the x-axis. Do you want to match this to the number on the y-axis?

Comment: You can say so. The distance between ticks on both axes must be equal on the screen (i.e. x2-x1 = y2-y1) . This is a graph of coordinates. The same distance between ticks will allow to get the correct azimuth (tilt of the graf) of movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use subplots to place each of them and match the number of ticks on the x-axis on the left side with the number of ticks on the y-axis on the left side. By specifying the overall graph size for the left side, I keep the left side area the same.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=2,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    column_widths=[0.5,0.5],
                    specs=[[{'rowspan':3},{}],
                           [None,{}],
                           [None,{}],
                          ],
                    vertical_spacing=0.01   
                    )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['time'],
                  y=df['x'],
                  mode='lines+markers',
                  type='scatter'
                        ), 1,2
                  )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['time'],
                  y=df['y'],
                  mode='lines+markers',
                  type='scatter'
                        ),2,2
                  )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['time'],
                  y=df['t'],
                  mode='lines+markers',
                  type='scatter'
                        ),3,2
                  )#.update_xaxes(tickangle=45)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['x'],
                  y=df['y'],
                  mode='markers',
                  type='scatter',
                        ), 1,1    
                )

fig.update_layout(
    height=700,
    template="plotly_white",
    margin=dict(t=10,b=0),
)

fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=-45)
#fig.layout['xaxis']['tickangle'] = 0
fig.layout['xaxis'].update(tickvals=np.linspace(df['x'].min(), df['x'].max(),9))

fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=1000, height=450)
fig.show()
```

[image]